# Showing different project-trees in different instances of emacs daemon

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon, neotree

At this point I usually hook up into my emacs-daemon using `emacsclient -a "" -c "$@"`. When I also want to display my project using Neotree, this works well for only one instance but if I open a file in another folder using this command, NeoTree stays at showing the structure of the folder I first startet my session in. Is there any way to always have it display the path in which the file I am editing is locating at while also using emacs as a daemon?